# Play Framework - migration from version 2.3.x to 2.4.1: how to determine whether a JSON value is JsUndefined

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to migrate my Play application from version 2.3.8 to 2.4.1... but I'm still facing some issues.

I use `play-json-zipper`, which always returns a `JsValue`... and thus the following statement doesn't work with Play 2.4.1:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

val json = JsObject(...)

val v = json.get(__ \ 'key) match { // json.get returns a JsValue
  case _: JsUndefined => Seq[JsValue]()
  case js: JsValue => js.as[JsArray].value
}
```

In Play 2.4.1 `JsUndefined` doesn't inherit from `JsValue` (they both inherit from `JsReadable`). My code is quite huge... and removing `play-json-zipper` would imply a considerable effort. Is there a workaround to determine whether the `JsValue` returned by `json.get(__ \ 'key)` is undefined?

Comment: `jsLookupRes.toOption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting one. The [commit](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/d0388d6bd1f770640027501a6bdddc51ac8e456c) says "JsUndefined should not be a JsValue". That's fair enough, I think it makes better sense for it to use the Some/None approach instead.

If you want to do exactly what you wrote there, can use something like this:

```
val v: Seq[JsValue] = (json \ "key").toOption.map {
  case JsArray(els) => els
  case _ => Seq[JsValue]()
} getOrElse(Seq[JsValue]())
```